# Can I contribute to an HSA after HDHP coverage ends mid year

Tags: united-states, hsa

I had a family HDHP for the first 8 months of 2018, and while I opened an HSA account during that time. Can I continue to make contributions to my HSA between September 1st 2018 and April 15th 2019 (up to the prorated max contribution limit)? Or does the prorated limit apply to people *currently* on an HDHP that *started* mid year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you know your [prorated HSA contribution limit](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/52452/10997), you have until April 15, 2019 to make HSA contributions for 2018 up to that limit. You don’t have to have HDHP coverage currently in order to make a contribution; you were an eligible individual for part of 2018, so you can make a 2018 contribution up to your limit.