# Correcting HSA contribution due to transfer of children's HDHP

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, health-insurance, hsa

I contributed the max ($6,750 for family in 2016). Now a court has ordered that my ex-wife take over health insurance for the kids, so my HDHP will cover only me, making my contribution max $3,350 for 2016.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is to determine your maximum HSA contribution for 2016.  The single coverage maximum for 2016 is $3350, but if you had family coverage for any complete months of 2016, your maximum will be higher.  There is a [worksheet in the Form 8889 instructions (line 3)](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8889/ch02.html#d0e378) that shows you how to prorate the maximum contribution limit for the case where your coverage changes during the year.  (Note: The linked instructions are for 2015.  When using the worksheet, substitute $6750 for the family coverage amount.)

After you have done that, you'll know how much you over-contributed.  You can do an excess contribution withdrawal to get your contribution down to the limit.  Just contact your HSA provider and tell them that you need to do an excess contribution withdrawal.  You won't pay any penalties for this, but if you had any investment gains on this extra contribution, you'll need to pay tax on it.  See [this question for more details](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/38917/10997).